# Ruby + Rspec: How should I be testing attr_accessor?

Tags: rspec

I have a `ReturnItem` class.

specs:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ReturnItem do
  #is this enough?
  it { should respond_to :chosen }
  it { should respond_to :chosen= }

end
```

class:

```
class ReturnItem
  attr_accessor :chosen
end
```

It seems a bit tedious since `attr_accessor` is used in practically every class. Is there a shortcut for this in rspec to test the default functionality of a getter and setter? Or do I have to go through the process of testing the getter and setter individually and manually for every attribute?

Comment: You'd think this be part of the core Rspec/Shoulda libraries, eh?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I created a custom rspec matcher for this:

`spec/custom/matchers/should_have_attr_accessor.rb`

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_attr_accessor do |field|
  match do |object_instance|
    object_instance.respond_to?(field) &&
      object_instance.respond_to?("#{field}=")
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |object_instance|
    "expected attr_accessor for #{field} on #{object_instance}"
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |object_instance|
    "expected attr_accessor for #{field} not to be defined on #{object_instance}"
  end

  description do
    "checks to see if there is an attr accessor on the supplied object"
  end
end
```

Then in my spec, I use it like so:

```
subject { described_class.new }
it { should have_attr_accessor(:foo) }
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of your matcher. I'm much more comfortable adding it to my code. For a more thorough matcher that also handles `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` take a look at https://gist.github.com/daronco/4133411#file-have_attr_accessor-rb

Comment: I believe this has been made part of any library and we can use this. Updated answer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

This is an updated version of the previous answer using RSpec 3, replacing `failure_message_for_should` for `failure_message` and `failure_message_for_should_not` for `failure_message_when_negated`:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_attr_accessor do |field|
  match do |object_instance|
    object_instance.respond_to?(field) &&
      object_instance.respond_to?("#{field}=")
  end

  failure_message do |object_instance|
    "expected attr_accessor for #{field} on #{object_instance}"
  end

  failure_message_when_negated do |object_instance|
    "expected attr_accessor for #{field} not to be defined on #{object_instance}"
  end

  description do
    "assert there is an attr_accessor of the given name on the supplied object"
  end
end
```