# What does 'failure_message_when_negated' mean in RSpec Matchers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28705325/1577357) and I didn't understand the `failure_message_when_negated` part.

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_attr_accessor do |field|
  match do |object_instance|
    object_instance.respond_to?(field) &&
      object_instance.respond_to?("#{field}=")
  end

  failure_message do |object_instance|
    "expected attr_accessor for #{field} on #{object_instance}"
  end

  failure_message_when_negated do |object_instance|
    "expected attr_accessor for #{field} not to be defined on #{object_instance}"
  end

  description do
    "assert there is an attr_accessor of the given name on the supplied object"
  end
end
```

What does it mean in simple words? I really appreciate clear and not-foo-bar explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it.

```
# if the Model has `attr_accessor` named `:promotion_type`
# `it { should_not have_attr_accessor :promotion_type }` test
# will return failure (call this `failure_message_when_negated`)
# because the Model is clearly has `:promotion_type`
failure_message_when_negated do |object_instance|
    "expected attr_accessor for #{field} not to be defined on #{object_instance}"
end
```

Example failure message:

```
1) Promotion should not assert there is an attr_accessor of the given name on the supplied object
     Failure/Error: it { should_not have_attr_accessor :promotion_type }
       expected attr_accessor for promotion_type not to be defined on #<Promotion:0x007fd939c840c8>
```